# Which one is the best practice with sass import with multiple @import and single @import statement?

Tags: sass

I am a newbie with sass and I see some documents use with multiple @import statement and another use with single @import statement.
So which one is the best practice or they are the same?

First way

```
@import
"Components/Utilities",
"Components/Header",
"Components/Navigation",
```

Second way

```
@import "Components/Utilities";
@import "Components/Header";
@import "Components/Navigation";
```

Answer (score 0):

The **second way** is a better and more conventional approach. A lot of big frameworks like [Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/bootstrap.scss) are using this way. So it seems to be the way to go. ;)